# How to convert Option[List[String]] to List[String] in Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, implicit

I am having `Option` of `List` of `String` like,
`Some(List("abc","def","ghi"))` and I need to convert to `List("abc","def","ghi")` in Scala. I Mean `Option[List[String]]` to `List[String]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check the documentation for [Option](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Option.html). You will find everything you'll need there.

Here are 2 ideas:

```
  val optlist = Some(List("abc", "def", "ghi"))
  val list = if (optlist.isDefined) optlist.get else Nil
  val list2 = optlist.getOrElse(Nil)
  println(list)
  println(list2)
```

Output:

```
List(abc, def, ghi)
List(abc, def, ghi)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove Option in Scala then you can use getOrElse() function.

Scala is a very strong typesafe language which detects compilation errors. In the else part you should return the same type of data, for example:

```
val nameOption : Option[String] = Some("ABC");
```

then to remove Option you should use getOrElse()

```
val name: String = nameOption.getOrElse(" ") #Empty String
```

Similarly, In your case,

```
val listOption = Some(List("abc", "def", "ghi"))

val list : List[String] = listOption.getOrElse(List.empty)
```

Output :

```
List(abc, def, ghi)
```